# Wanted to upgrade my Old Ubuntu Desktop(installed in 2011) to Current stable version

Tags: 11.04

Update Manager is asking me to update to 11.10 which is old.

I wanted to upgrade my Old Ubuntu Desktop(installed in 2011) to Current stable version. Old configuration is really very stable and there are no more updates available for this version. This is the only reason, I am looking forward for updating same to current version.

Please suggest my options.
Thank you.

Comment: Why not just do a fresh install of 14.04 LTS? But it will be better if you add hardware detail to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Jumping to multiple versions up, better way would be backup, re-install and restore the needed data back. The current versions for LTS 14.04.2 a jump over 5 versions and 15.04 is 7 versions. So I would recommend re-install path.